# TYPO3 flexform nested tabs?

Tags: xml, typo3, backend

Is it possible to have nested tabs in a flexform?

Well, it's possible to create them but no values are saved.
I got the following code to create the nested tabs:
flexform.xml

```
<tab1>
    <TCEforms>
        <config>
             <type>flex</type>
                  <ds>
                      <default>FILE:EXT:extension/Configuration/FlexForms/flexform_subtabs.xml</default>
                  </ds>
        </config>
    </TCEforms>
</tab1>
```

Inside the *flexform_subtabs.xml* other tabs are created.
Everything looks good in the plugin but I cannot save the values.

Is there anything wrong with my code?

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 3):

As of 09/2011, it was not possible, and IMHO still is not. My sources are:

[This mailing list post](http://lists.typo3.org/pipermail/typo3-dev/2006-November/020841.html) 11/2006

> If you mean tabbed form inside tabbed form, I afraid this is not 
>   possible (though I can be wrong). Tabs are created from sheets but can
>   be no sheets inside sheets.

[This bug report #19169](http://forge.typo3.org/issues/19196) 09/2011. No target version is named yet, therefore no solution available.

> The Problem still exists in TYPO 4.5.5 but the patch does not work